# why is my section tag overlapping my div container? I'm trying to out the section under the homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a new section but the  tag is overlapping my home page. I tried adding divs, removing divs, and adding more sections but can't get to the solution. Is it because of my styling or because of my HTML?

```css
/* Base Styles -------------------- */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Body */

body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("img/body-image1.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Navigation Styles */

.row {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.row li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

.row li:hover,
.row li:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #48a8ce;
}


/* Media queries for home page */

@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}


/* Cursor for Typewriter */

.txt-type>.txt {
  border-right: 0.2rem solid #777;
}


/* Aspirations Section */


/* .section-head {
      padding-left: 500px;
      padding-top: 0px;
    } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Carlos Gonzales</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home"></a>Home</li>
          <li>
            <a href="#aspirations"></a>Aspirations</li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about"></a>About</li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact"></a>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Carlos Gonzales The
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="3000" data-words='["Developer", "Creator", "Entrepreneur"]'></span>
    </h1>
    <h2>Welcome to my website !</h2>
  </div>


  <section id="aspirations" class="aspiration-section">

    <h2 class="section-head">Aspirations</h2>
    <p>My aspiration after becoming a paid developer run far. After getting paid for my code I would like to learn on for about 5 more years and than start working for myself. I will expand my brand by using resources like Youtube and Twitter. Funding my
      startup and owning a successful one for me is a lifetime goal. I would love to teach grade school kids how to code because I believe learning this skill at an early age is really benefiting. I would also like to develop an app people can use on
      their phone to make their nyc public parking experience convenient and free of expense of private parking lot fees.
    </p>
    <a href="Contact" class="btn-aspirations">Help Develop ParkingBud Now</a>

  </section>



  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Carlos Gonzales</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home"></a>Home</li>
          <li>
            <a href="#aspirations"></a>Aspirations</li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about"></a>About</li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact"></a>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Carlos Gonzales The
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="3000" data-words='["Developer", "Creator", "Entrepreneur"]'></span>
    </h1>
    <h2>Welcome to my website !</h2>
  </div>


  <section id="aspirations" class="aspiration-section">

    <h2 class="section-head">Aspirations</h2>
    <p>My aspiration after becoming a paid developer run far. After getting paid for my code I would like to learn on for about 5 more years and than start working for myself. I will expand my brand by using resources like Youtube and Twitter. Funding my
      startup and owning a successful one for me is a lifetime goal. I would love to teach grade school kids how to code because I believe learning this skill at an early age is really benefiting. I would also like to develop an app people can use on
      their phone to make their nyc public parking experience convenient and free of expense of private parking lot fees.
    </p>
    <a href="Contact" class="btn-aspirations">Help Develop ParkingBud Now</a>

  </section>



  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to put the sections under the div container . Sorry for the "out" typo meant to say "put" .

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Not sure why you have 2 different `<html>` tags in the same document, looks like 2 different pages but they are being rendered together. Are you trying to make multiple pages here?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the duplicate `html` and `body` tags. Then I added the additional sections, each one following the previous, inside the same `body`. I also noticed you closed your `<a>` tags before the label in your navigation, fixed that too by moving `</a>` after the link labels.

I think this is what you were going for? Something like this?

```css
/* Base Styles -------------------- */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Body */

body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("img/body-image1.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Navigation Styles */

.row {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.row li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}

.row li:hover,
.row li:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #48a8ce;
}


/* Media queries for home page */

@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}


/* Cursor for Typewriter */

.txt-type>.txt {
  border-right: 0.2rem solid #777;
}


/* Aspirations Section */


/* .section-head {
      padding-left: 500px;
      padding-top: 0px;
    } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Carlos Gonzales</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#aspirations">Aspirations</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Carlos Gonzales The
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="3000" data-words='["Developer", "Creator", "Entrepreneur"]'></span>
    </h1>
    <h2>Welcome to my website !</h2>
  </div>


  <section id="aspirations" class="aspiration-section">

    <h2 class="section-head">Aspirations</h2>
    <p>My aspiration after becoming a paid developer run far. After getting paid for my code I would like to learn on for about 5 more years and than start working for myself. I will expand my brand by using resources like Youtube and Twitter. Funding my
      startup and owning a successful one for me is a lifetime goal. I would love to teach grade school kids how to code because I believe learning this skill at an early age is really benefiting. I would also like to develop an app people can use on
      their phone to make their nyc public parking experience convenient and free of expense of private parking lot fees.
    </p>
    <a href="Contact" class="btn-aspirations">Help Develop ParkingBud Now</a>

  </section>
  
  
  <section id="about" class="about-section">

    <h2 class="section-head">About</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia feugiat pharetra. Cras gravida lobortis pellentesque. Etiam pellentesque maximus tincidunt. Mauris urna nulla, vestibulum vitae euismod sit amet, consectetur ut ante. Ut molestie, nunc non vehicula ullamcorper, sapien lorem vestibulum est, in pulvinar nibh est et dolor. Morbi at posuere eros. Maecenas ornare risus id felis aliquam, quis lacinia mauris faucibus. Nunc ut sagittis neque. Vivamus imperdiet tristique lorem. Suspendisse tellus massa, iaculis in ultricies in, gravida non ex. Phasellus nec dolor magna.
    </p>

  </section>
  
  <section id="contact" class="contact-section">

    <h2 class="section-head">Contact</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia feugiat pharetra. Cras gravida lobortis pellentesque. Etiam pellentesque maximus tincidunt. Mauris urna nulla, vestibulum vitae euismod sit amet, consectetur ut ante. Ut molestie, nunc non vehicula ullamcorper, sapien lorem vestibulum est, in pulvinar nibh est et dolor. Morbi at posuere eros. Maecenas ornare risus id felis aliquam, quis lacinia mauris faucibus. Nunc ut sagittis neque. Vivamus imperdiet tristique lorem. Suspendisse tellus massa, iaculis in ultricies in, gravida non ex. Phasellus nec dolor magna.
    </p>

  </section>



  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted for the sections. But i ran your code and now I think something is wrong with the css because the "aspirations" section is still overlapping the div = container . Thanks for your help again.